# Vim - Remove autocompletion menu

Tags: vim

I use the [SuperTab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) plugin and every time I tab to get some completion, if there is more than one possibility, a menu pops up under my cursor. 
 I would like to remove this menu, I removed `set wildmenu` from my vimrc but it doesn't work.

**This is what I'm trying to get rid of:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove that menu with:

```
:set completeopt-=menu
:set completeopt-=menuone
```

See `:help completeopt`.

But…

- the inability to see the suggestions makes completion *a lot* less useful,
- SuperTab *may or may not* care about those options.

Comment: It works exactly as I want now, even with superTab, thanks!